# Implement or use or code MVVM model in Microsoft Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, mvvm

I cant see any template project to use MVVM model in Visual Studio. Only can see the MVC model template. How to implement or use or code MVVM model in visual studio or in asp.net?. Do we need to use some other IDE or language for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new project with MVC template and MVC core reference, you will se some ViewModels are created as AccountViewModel etc. under Models folder.Its up to you to use ViewModels,they are not necessary but definitely useful.Its better to create ViewModels Folder and put your ViewModels in it.